# Is there a pandas function to re-organize a dataframe around one column (and total rows with a specific column value)?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that contains every movie in a certain genre and the year it was released (plus some other stuff). I want to reorganize the dataframe so that it contains the number of films per year (and each year appears only once). Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Could you please add a [mre](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (also look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)) to your question? ([How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask))

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and [value_counts](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html)

For instance,

```py
df.groupby("year")["genre"].value_counts()
```

will show you the number of movies in each genre for each year.

Without seeing your data and things you've tried I can't help much more. Please try to show these things.